# Is there R function for crossover?

Tags: r

I want to have function two computer the 1-crossover for two strings.

the input are two binary strings, with the same length, and the output is there 1-crossover.

For example, the output of crossover(11100, 10000)

10100, 11000
11100, 10000

Or I can write the function by myself, but is there any string split or sting Congregation function to use in R?

Thanks!

Comment: Could you provide an explanation of how you derive the outputs from the inputs? (In other words, define 1-crossover.)

Comment: You should also quote your binary strings: `crossover("11100","10000") ` otherwise they are decimal numbers.

Comment: I'm guessing this is some kind of genetics thing? You want all unique patterns where `C_i` is `A_i` or `B_i`?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a stupidly inefficient implementation:

```
crossover=function(A,B){
    require(e1071)
    b = bincombinations(length(A))
    t(unique(apply(b, 1, function(r){r*A+(1-r)*B}),MARGIN=2))    
}
```

Its args are vectors of 1s and 0s, and its return is a matrix of crossovers:

```
> crossover(c(1,1,1,0,0),c(1,0,0,0,0))
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    1    0    0    0    0
[2,]    1    0    1    0    0
[3,]    1    1    0    0    0
[4,]    1    1    1    0    0
```

The inefficiency comes from it computing all combinations of A with B and then taking only the unique ones. There's bound to be a better way.

If you really want to work on strings then you can find string splitting and pasting answers yourself.

Comment: Would `combn` not work?